# How do I disable a jquery-ui draggable?

Tags: jquery-ui

How do I disable a jQuery draggable, e.g. during an UpdatePanel postback?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Could create a DisableDrag(myObject) and a EnableDrag(myObject) function

```
myObject.draggable( 'disable' )
```

Then

```
myObject.draggable( 'enable' )
```

Comment: This works. Full docs for draggable() are [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#options). Same goes for sortable() objects (if you're allowing drag-n-drop reordering.)

Comment: Which is to say that [the draggable() docs are (now?) here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/), with nickb's link, above, going [to the demo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). ;)

Comment: This gives me "cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'"

Comment: Mian Haseeb: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955630/jquery-ui-draggable-error-cannot-call-methods-prior-to-init-in-updating-to-ve

Answer (score 74):

To temporarily disable the draggable behavior use:

```
$('#item-id').draggable( "disable" )
```

To remove the draggable behavior permanently use:

```
$('#item-id').draggable( "destroy" )
```

Comment: I found that 'disable' has a css related side effect, but destroy works flawlessly.

Comment: @jedanput the side effect of using disable is the draggable elements have a greyed out appearance. destroy seems to leave the appearance alone.

Answer (score 25):

To enable/disable draggable in jQuery I used:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ disabled: true });          

$("#draggable").draggable({ disabled: false });
```

@Calciphus answer didn't work for me with the opacity problem, so I used:

```
div.ui-state-disabled.ui-draggable-disabled {opacity: 1;}
```

Worked on mobile devices either.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nn5aL/1/

[enable](/questions/tagged/enable)[disable](/questions/tagged/disable)[draggable](/questions/tagged/draggable)[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[opacity](/questions/tagged/opacity)[problem](/questions/tagged/problem)[html](/questions/tagged/html)

Comment: Your JSfiddle doesn't seem to be working. The buttons don't click (using the latest Chrome). I tried updating it to links and calling `button()` but that didn't help.

Comment: out of all the solutions given, this one was the only one that worked 100% for me - all the others (using combinations of disable/destroy etc) just didn't fix the css issue. In my app using drag+drop I found the opacity was different for those elements that had been dragged since initialisation compared to those that hadn't been touched. All very messy. Thanks to @CarinaPilar for both the solution and the jsfiddle to prove it.

Answer (score 11):

It took me a little while to figure out how to disable draggable on drop—use `ui.draggable` to reference the object being dragged from inside the drop function:

```
$("#drop-target").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.draggable("disable", 1); // *not* ui.draggable("disable", 1);
        …
    }
});
```

HTH someone

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution appears to work well when using draggable/droppable directives in AngularJS.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like no one looked at the original documentation. May be there was no it at that time))

Initialize a draggable with the disabled option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ disabled: true });
```

Get or set the disabled option, after init.

```
//getter
var disabled = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "disabled" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: This works but has a side effect of making my div about 50% opacity... I have no idea why.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Any time you disable something in jQuery, it adds "ui-state-disabled" class. You can remove it with:

$(".ui-draggable").removeClass("ui-state-disabled")

Answer (score 7):

In the case of a dialog, it has a property called draggable, set it to false.

```
$("#yourDialog").dialog({
    draggable: false
});
```

Eventhough the question is old, i tried the proposed solution and it did not work for the dialog. Hope this may help others like me.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is specifically related to jQueryUI *Dialogs*, but I found your post helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

The following is what this would look like inside of `.draggable({});`

```
$("#yourDraggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid" ,
    start: function(){ 
        $(this).css("opacity",0.3);
    },
    stop: function(){ 
        $(this).draggable( 'disable' )
    },
    opacity: 0.7,
    helper: function () { 
        $copy = $(this).clone(); 
        $copy.css({
            "list-style":"none",
            "width":$(this).outerWidth()
        }); 
        return $copy; 
    },
    appendTo: 'body',
    scroll: false
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a simpler and elegant solution that doesn't mess up with classes, styles, opacities and stuff.

For the draggable element - you add 'start' event which will execute every time you try to move the element somewhere. You will have a condition which move is not legal. For the moves that are illegal - prevent them with 'e.preventDefault();' like in the code below.

```
    $(".disc").draggable({
        revert: "invalid", 
        cursor: "move",
        start: function(e, ui){                
            console.log("element is moving");

            if(SOME_CONDITION_FOR_ILLEGAL_MOVE){
                console.log("illegal move");
                //This will prevent moving the element from it's position
                e.preventDefault();
            }    

        }
    });
```

You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `draggable` attribute from

```
<span draggable="true">Label</span>
```

to

```
<span draggable="false">Label</span>
```