# draggable switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It might seem a little dull and basic, but I'm actually having trouble to find a good solution to my problem.

I'm using jQuery to make nice draggable elements. What I'd like to do is to anchor the draggable element wherever I want, with a button/link there is on it.

You could think of disable/enable the draggable when the button is clicked : it has the effect I want, but it sets a weird effect on the draggable, rendering it half white (which is the effect you would expect from disable, I'm not arguing on that).

Bottom-line is : how do I apply - and more importantly - remove the draggable property on the element? Is there any sort of :

`$( "#draggable" ).draggable(false);`

that would simply make my element normal again, or just prevent it from moving without altering its appearance?

Thanks in advance!

Edit : I have used the `.draggable("disable")` function and it changes the element's appearance, therefore I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can disable the element from being draggable :

```
$('#draggable').draggable( "disable" );
```

[See the docs here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#method-disable)

Comment: But it actually disables it, putting a visual effect on it. I don't want it to change appearance, simply behavior. I'll take a look at the docs though, thanks!

Comment: @GabrielTheron appearance can be fixed using CSS surely ?

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search before you ask a question, thanks =)

This disables draggable

```
myObject.draggable( 'disable' )
```

This enables it

```
myObject.draggable( 'enable' )
```

There was already question here answering your question: [How do I disable a jquery-ui draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324044/how-to-disable-jquery-ui-draggable)

Comment: As I specified in my question and earlier comment, I have tested this function already, and do not want to use it because it alters the appearance of my elements. Do you know a way to have this function alter the behavior of the element without changing its appearance with "disable" function?

Comment: You'd think you would have figured out to appearance would have been a css issue. Well, you got your answer, good luck in whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Googled it, ended up here ∞