# What is this parameter when disabling a draggable?

Tags: jquery

What is the 1 parameter below when disabling a draggable, is it the number of seconds to wait until the draggable is disabled ?

```
$("#drop-target").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.draggable("disable", 1); 
});
```

I seen this in answer by Boblet at question : [How do I disable a jquery-ui draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324044/how-to-disable-jquery-ui-draggable)

If this constructor is not valid why does it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing. There is no need of passing 1. I couldn't find this constructor in jquery draggable.

Where you got this?

Comment: because javascript ignores the additional parameter.