# jQuery-UI draggable error 'cannot call methods prior to init', in updating to version 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, upgrade

I was working the draggable plugin fine while using jQuery-UI 1.8.2, then I changed to 1.10.1. The major difference I found was that in enabling and disabling the plugin, I no longer needed to use:

```
$this.draggable('option', 'disabled', true);
```

but could simply use

```
$this.draggable('disable');
```

But then I realized there's another problem. I get this error, which messes up my entire program, and I don't know how to fix it:

> Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'enable'

To fix it, I ensured that I always call `$this.draggable('enable');` before any further options, but it didn't make a difference. What's the problem?

Comment: Your error says `$this.draggable('enable');` is called before `$this.draggable();`.

Have you checked the execution flow ?

Comment: Yep, I'd made a mistake in understanding the flow, I was able to make sure I did `$this.draggable()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The meaning of your error is : `$this.draggable('enable');` is called before `$this.draggable();`.

Check the execution flow of your progam : make sure that you have indeed initialized the plugin (e.g : called `$this.draggable();`) before trying to do anything with it.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.  It is a confusing rhetorical question.  I think it should be rephrased to be an answer more directly.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on what LeGEC said...

`$this.draggable();` is being called before `$this.draggable('enable');`

For me the solution would be to chain the event like this...

```
$this.draggable().draggable('disable');
```

First declaring that $this is a draggable, then declaring that it is dissabled

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when upgrading from jquery 1.6.1 to 1.9.1

```
var tr$ = $('<tr>', { draggable: 'true' });
```

threw "cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization"

modified to:

```
var tr$ = $('<tr>');
if(!('draggable' in document.createElement('span'))) {
  //handle old browsers                
} else {
  tr$.attr('draggable', 'true');
}
```

Posting in case it helps someone else to see it this way.