# Revert a draggable feature of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this code,

```
  window.addEvent('domready', function() {
         new Sortables('.homepagemodule CAPTION', {
            clone: true,
            revert: true,
            opacity: 0.7,
            onStart: function() {
               dndMovingModule = this.element.parentNode.parentNode.id.toUpperCase();
            },
            onComplete: function() {
               dndDroppedOntoModule = this.element.parentNode.parentNode.id.toUpperCase();
               if (typeof dndMovingModule != "undefined" && typeof dndDroppedOntoModule != "undefined" && dndMovingModule != dndDroppedOntoModule) {
                  var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + year + "/save_setting?L=" + league_id + "&TITLE=MODULE&VALUE=" + dndMovingModule + "," + dndDroppedOntoModule;
                  // alert("calling: " + url);
                  makeHttpRequest(url);
                  setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 250);
               }
            }
         });
      });
```

What I have understood is it adds the draggable feature to the caption.
**Since this is written in an external javascript which I cannot edit, how can I remove its effect?**

**I tried setting :**

`draggable(disable:true)`

```
.unwrap()
```

But nothing seems to work.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable a jquery-ui draggable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324044/how-do-i-disable-a-jquery-ui-draggable)

Comment: whats the code inside Sortables?

Comment: https://github.com/pablohess/html5-blackboard/tree/master/img